# cannot form correct string

Tags: php, string

i have folllowing code to create sql query

```
$sql= '(SELECT ticket_id,message,created,2 from '.TICKET_MESSAGE_TABLE.' msg where msg.ticket_id ='.db_input($id).' ) UNION (SELECT ticket_id,response,created,1 from '.TICKET_RESPONSE_TABLE.' resp where resp.ticket_id= '.db_input($id).' )UNION (SELECT ticket_id,note,created,3 FROM '.TICKET_NOTE-TABLE .' note WHERE note.ticket_id='.db_input($id).' ) order by created';

echo "sql:  ".$sql;
```

when i run this i get

```
sql: 0 note WHERE note.ticket_id=2 ) order by created
```

can anyone pls explain where the 0 is coming from and why the string is not formed correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TICKET_NOTE-TABLE`

This would be easier to spot if you had wrapped your input in some sane fashion :)

```
$sql= '(SELECT ticket_id,message,created,2 from '.TICKET_MESSAGE_TABLE.
      ' msg where msg.ticket_id ='.db_input($id).
      ' ) UNION (SELECT ticket_id,response,created,1 from '.TICKET_RESPONSE_TABLE.
      ' resp where resp.ticket_id= '.db_input($id).
      ' )UNION (SELECT ticket_id,note,created,3 FROM '.TICKET_NOTE-TABLE .
      ' note WHERE note.ticket_id='.db_input($id).
      ' ) order by created';

echo "sql:  ".$sql;
```

Furthermore, I hope that `db_input()` function is there to prevent [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). And I hope it's well-implemented. (I think using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) is easier *and* more legible.)